# What is the point using "AS" keyword in SQL when aliasing can be done without it?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

1. Select salary*12 as "Annual Salary" from Employee;
2. Select salary*12 "Annual Salary" from Employee;

Both queries will give the same result, would "AS" make some difference? if yes, what it is? if no, then what is point using it?

Comment: According to ANSI/ISO SQL the `AS` keyword is optional. But some dbms products want it, while others don't want it...

Comment: There's also the `alias=columnValue` syntax; i.e. `select x=1, 2 as y, 3 z` used in some DBMS systems.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think the reason is simple.  Consider code such as the following:

```
select a, b, c, d
. . .
```

It is very easy to occasionally skip the comma:

```
select a b, c, d
```

If you don't use `as` then this looks like correct code and it can be difficult to figure out.  If you *always* use `as` for column aliases, then you know it is incorrect.

Comment: Great illustration of an issue from skipping the `as`. Very nice!

Comment: That's a great point and I should have thought about it when writing my answer. +1.

Comment: Not exactly the OP's question but the combination of using AS and putting each column of a select on a new row with the comma at the beginning makes it very easy to quickly identify when this kind of circumstance occurs

Comment: @AnthonyHancock . . . Except for the comma at the beginning of the line, I basically agree.  English and most other languages do not start lines with punctuation, so it looks really, really awkward.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I agree that it may look a bit awkward, but if you've ever forgotten a comma between columns and tried to figure out where, it is a lot easier to just trace a line down the screen instead of weaving back and forth at the end of every line trying to find it. Everyone has their own slight syntax variances though.

Answer (score 13):

1. Readability.
   Imagin your query have 20, 50 or even 100 columns. using `As` will help anyone reading the query to know what is a column and what is an alias.
2. Compatability.
   If you plan on ever moving to a RDBMS, that RDBMS might not support short-hand aliasing.

Also, it's worth mentioning that some DBA's don't like the use of `as` keywords - Here's [Aaron Bertrand's article about it](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases). Personally, I don't agree with this post (though other posts in the bad habits series are no less then briliant IMHO)

Comment: I'm with AB on this one

Comment: I'm with ZoharPeled and AaronBertrand wrt disapproving of `SELECT expression alias` - too vulnerable to errors, like missing commas. As for `SELECT expression AS alias` vs `SELECT alias = expression`, although I prefer the latter, I think of it as a matter of emphasis: if you want to emphasize the expression by letting it come first, use `AS`, if you want to emphasize the new field name, use `=`. // In other languages, I may similarly say `dest := source` or `source =: dest`, or `field OF record` vs `record.field` (or the less common `record 's field`.

Comment: +1 for bringing up Aaron Bertrand, although I disagree with preferring `=` over `as`.  Unfortunately, `=` means different things in different databases.  It is not just a question of "style" but of actual semantic differences.

Comment: @GordonLinoff very true, but the article does take great care to express (in the first paragraph) that this is a SQL server specific preference and that if portable code is your priority that the opinion does not apply.

Answer (score 1):

Gordon has shown a great issue.
The `as` keyword meaning is easy to understand upon multiple tables `select` query. For instance, if you use query based on several conditions of the same table. In this case, `as` allows to make an alias of the table and whole subquery with easy to read and failsafe `alias.Field` output.