# Can someone help me with this query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Each row in this table contains a column called ParentFamilyId, which tells you which parent family any family belongs to (the All categories family - number 25 - has no parent, and so sits at the top of the hierarchy).

Create a query which links 3 tables using outer joins as follows:

```
Table       Alias
tblFamily   Family
tblFamily   ParentFamily
tblFamily   TopFamily
```

Add calculated columns to your query so that it displays all 25 familes:

[image]

If you display the families in FamilyName order, you should see something like this.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT Family.FamilyName FamilyName,
       CASE WHEN Family.FamilyName = 'All categories' THEN Family.FamilyName 
            ELSE CONCAT(topfamily.FamilyName, '>', Parentfamily.FamilyName, '>', Family.FamilyName) 
       END AS 'Family path'
FROM tblFamily Family
LEFT JOIN tblFamily ParentFamily ON Family.ParentFamilyId = ParentFamily.FamilyID
LEFT JOIN tblFamily TopFamily ON TopFamily.FamilyName = 'All categories'
order by Family.FamilyName
```

I have the correct results but is this the best way to do it? I have been out of touch from development for a long time so practicing basics.

Comment: the questions suggests create a query which links 3 tables using outer joins: tblFamily as Family, tblFamily as ParentFamily, tblFamily as TopFamily

Comment: If you're not 100% sure on how many possible levels in a hierarchy there are, you might use a recursive CTE instead. Your solution seems fine if there can only be three levels though.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: I don't post as an answer as I am not sure but I think you could use an OR rather than two left join.

Comment: Maybe a UNION over 2 left joins

Comment: You might also want to read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1):

> Create a query which links 3 tables using outer joins as follows:
>   `Table       Alias`
>   `tblFamily   Family`
>   `tblFamily   ParentFamily`
>   `tblFamily   TopFamily`

I would say unless your teacher is going to use this example as a reason why you should use recursive ctes, this is a terrible homework assignment. 
That being said, your query is not actually that far from the correct answer:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Family.FamilyName, Parentfamily.FamilyName, topfamily.FamilyName) As 'Family Name',
       topfamily.FamilyName + 
       ISNULL('>' + Parentfamily.FamilyName, '') + 
       ISNULL('>' + Family.FamilyName, '') As 'Family path'
FROM tblFamily As TopFamily 
LEFT JOIN tblFamily As ParentFamily ON ParentFamily.ParentFamilyId = TopFamily.FamilyID
LEFT JOIN tblFamily As Family ON Family.ParentFamilyId = ParentFamily.FamilyID
WHERE TopFamily.ParentFamily.ParentFamilyId IS NULL -- So of someone changes the `All categories` text your query will not have to change
order by Family.FamilyName
```

Notes:

- Your first column, `Family.FamilyName FamilyName,` is wrong since `Family` might not always contains rows. Also, [**always** use the `as` keyword for aliases.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42326469/what-is-the-point-using-as-keyword-in-sql-when-aliasing-can-be-done-without-it)
  My first column use `COALESCE` to get the first non-null value of the three aliases.
- Your second column assumes it's either 1 level or 3, but the picture shows otherwise. In my second column, I've taken advantage of the fact that using the `+` concatenation operator between `null` and a varchar value gives you null - so in case the `Family.FamilyName` is null, the result would be `topfamily.FamilyName > Parentfamily.FamilyName`.
- The order of the tables in an outer join is critical. Since the `TopFamily` alias will always be selected it must be the first table in the from clause, followed by the `ParentFamily` alias, and last the `Family` alias.
- The join between tables is always on right table.id = left table.parentId
- The where clause now contains a condition that will always be true for top level families, even if you have more than one or the name changes.

Answer (score 0):

Like @ZLK suggested, you may want to try a recursive CTE. Here's an example.

```
WITH
tblFamily
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( 1, 0, 'All categories')
    , ( 1, 2, 'Something1')
    , ( 1, 3, 'Something2')
    , ( 1, 4, 'Something3')
    , ( 1, 5, 'Something4')
    , ( 1, 6, 'Something5')
    , ( 2, 10, 'Something10')
    , ( 3, 11, 'Something11')
    , ( 4, 12, 'Something12')
    , ( 5, 13, 'Something13')
    , ( 6, 14, 'Something14')
    ) tbl ([ParentFamilyId], [FamilyID], [FamilyName]) 
)
,
tblFamily_relate ([ParentFamilyId], [FamilyID], [FamilyName], [FamilyTree], [FamilyLevel])
AS
(
    SELECT 
          Family.[ParentFamilyId]
        , Family.[FamilyID]
        , Family.[FamilyName]
        , [FamilyTree] = cast(Family.[FamilyName] as varchar(max))
        , [FamilyLevel] = 0
    FROM 
        tblFamily Family
    WHERE 
        Family.[FamilyID] IN(SELECT [ParentFamilyId] FROM tblFamily)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
          Family.[ParentFamilyId]
        , Family.[FamilyID]
        , Family.[FamilyName]
        , [FamilyTree] = cast(ParentFamily.[FamilyName] as varchar(max)) + cast(Family.[FamilyName] as varchar(max))  
        , [FamilyLevel] + 1
    FROM 
        tblFamily Family
        INNER JOIN tblFamily_relate ParentFamily  ON Family.ParentFamilyId = ParentFamily.FamilyID
    WHERE 
        Family.[FamilyID] NOT IN(SELECT [ParentFamilyId] FROM tblFamily)
)
SELECT * FROM tblFamily_relate
```

Comment: While I agree that in SQL Server, [the answer to every question about how to query hierarchical data is using a recursive cte.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44405165/self-join-query/44405924#44405924), I think this question is a homework question, so the OP might just need to use the left join (wrong) approach.